# Mockito and mock webservicetemplate

Tags: java, spring, jaxb, mockito, webservicetemplate

I use `mockito 3` as follow:

```
Mockito.when(webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(Mockito.anyString(),
                ArgumentMatchers.<JAXBElement<TypeA>>any()))
                .thenReturn(responseA);
Mockito.when(webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(Mockito.anyString(),
                ArgumentMatchers.<JAXBElement<TypeB>>any()))
                .thenReturn(responseB);
```

The problem is that mockito returns always the `responseB`. 
Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are mocking the same method `marshalSendAndReceive` in both cases.

It appears therefore that the response is always `responseB`, because the code that is returning `responseB` is invoked last.

Is the method overloaded using different types of parameters, or do `TypeA` and `TypeB` share the same parent class?